# Route Model Binding multiple types of Models to the same Controller method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, eloquent

I am trying to figure out the correct way to implement a polymorphic relationship in Laravel using the example case of allowing the same "Comment" model to have a relationship with both "Posts" and "Videos".

This is the same example as in the Laravel docs, as follows:

```
posts
    id - integer
    title - string
    body - text

videos
    id - integer
    title - string
    url - string

comments
    id - integer
    body - text
    commentable_id - integer
    commentable_type - string
```

I have the models set up with the relationships back and forth - no issue there. My question is how to make most efficient use of the CommentsController? I would like to be able to use the same CommentsController@store method to store any type of comment, whether it be for a post or a video.

This, rather than the alternative of having a CommentsController@storePostComment and a CommentsController@storeVideoComment.

I have my routes set up as follows:

```
Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments', 'CommentsController@store'); 
Route::post('/videos/{video}/comments', 'CommentsController@store');
```

I have my CommentsController@store method set up as follows, currently for **Posts only**:

```
class CommentsController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Post $post)
    {
        $post->addComment(request('body'));      

        return back(); 
    }
}
```

Laravel's route model binding grabs the correct Post and the addComment() method saves the comment.

My question is how can I modify this to accept either a Post or a Video to the same method? I am sure this is the correct way to do it rather than creating separate methods for each, but not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

Try Using SEGMENT

```
public function store($data)  //{post} or {video} comes here
{
   if(Request::segment(1) == 'posts'){
       $post = new Post;
       $post->addComment(request('body'));
   }else if(Request::segment(1) == 'videos'){
       $video = new Video;
       $video->addComment(request('url'));
   }     
   return back(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am going to do it this way for now! I was hoping there was a way to automatically detect the type and assign... something along the lines of an interface, but will keep trying to figure that out.

Comment: Have you gotten any further regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

You can also instantiate the model on the fly from a string, although you'd probably want to whitelist valid model types:

```php
public function store(str $model)
{
    $model = 'App\\Models\\'.ucfirst(Request::segment(1));
    $model = new $model;
    $model->addComment(request('body'));      

    return back(); 
}
```